# Implement Timer using React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React from 'react';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import Confetti from 'react-confetti';
import { useStopwatch } from 'react-timer-hook';

import Die from './components/Die';
import './style.css';
import Timer from './components/Timer';
import Rolls from './components/rolls';

function App() {
  const { seconds, minutes, hours, isRunning, start, pause, reset } =
    useStopwatch({ autoStart: true });

  const [dice, setDice] = React.useState(allNewDice());
  const [tenzies, setTenzies] = React.useState(false);

  const [time, setTime] = React.useState({});
  const [hasStarted, setHasStarted] = React.useState(() => false);
  const [bestTime, setBestTime] = React.useState(() =>
    localStorage.getItem('best-time')
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('best-time'))
      : ''
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTime({ seconds: seconds, minutes: minutes, hours: hours });
  }, [seconds, minutes, hours]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const firstValue = dice[0].value;
    const allHeld = dice.every((die) => die.isHeld === true);
    const allEqual = dice.every((die) => die.value === firstValue);
    if (allEqual && allHeld) {
      setTenzies(true);
      //if (time < bestTime || !bestTime) {
      //  setBestTime(time);
      //  localStorage.setItem('best-time', time);
      //}
    }
  }, [dice]);

  function generateNewDie() {
    return { value: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6), isHeld: false, id: nanoid() };
  }

  function allNewDice() {
    const newDice = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      newDice.push(generateNewDie());
    }
    return newDice;
  }

  function rollDice() {
    if (!tenzies) {
      setDice((oldDice) =>
        oldDice.map((die) => {
          return die.isHeld === true ? die : generateNewDie();
        })
      );
    } else {
      setTenzies(false);
      setDice(allNewDice());
    }
  }

  function holdDice(id) {
    setDice((oldDice) =>
      oldDice.map((die) => {
        return die.id === id ? { ...die, isHeld: !die.isHeld } : die;
      })
    );
  }

  const diceElements = dice.map((die) => (
    <Die
      key={die.id}
      value={die.value}
      isHeld={die.isHeld}
      holdDice={() => holdDice(die.id)}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <main>
      {tenzies && <Confetti />}
      <h1 className="title">Tenzies</h1>
      <p className="instructions">
        Roll until all dice are the same. Click each die to freeze it at its
        current value between rolls.
      </p>
      <div className="dice-container">{diceElements}</div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="total-timer">
          <Timer best={true} timer={time} />
          <Timer timer={time} />
        </div>
        <button type="button" className="roll-dice" onClick={rollDice}>
          {tenzies ? 'New Game' : 'Roll'}
        </button>
        <div className="total-rolls">
          <Rolls best={true} />
          <Rolls />
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Is it a good practice having `Effect Hook` render my page every second of the timer??

`Timer`

```
export default function Timer(props) {
  const styles = {
    color: props.best ? '#59e391' : 'white',
  };
  return (
    <div className="timer" style={styles}>
      {props.best ? <span>Best Time : </span> : <span>Your Time : </span>}
      <span className="digits">
        {props.timer.hours ? props.timer.hours : '00'}
      </span>
      <span>:</span>
      <span className="digits">
        {props.timer.minutes ? props.timer.minutes : '00'}
      </span>
      <span>:</span>
      <span className="digits">
        {props.timer.seconds ? props.timer.seconds : '00'}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Nothing calls `setTime`, and it's not clear what the `timer` prop is supposed to be. I might start by having something in `timer` first then worry about passing it to something else.

Comment: @DaveNewton i used Effect Hook to render the timer but is it a good practice having this hook render my page every second or there is another implementation?

Comment: :shrug: Seems fine; an alternative would be to send the values directly to the `Timer` display component and avoid a layer of state updates--but I don't really know if there's an exciting reason to make the change, would need to try it out.